Concept of Shunyata and Purnata in Upanishads
I am fascinated by how the Upanishads have assimilated two distinct philosophical thoughts: the concept of Shunya (emptiness) from the Nirvana Upanishad and the concept of Purnam (wholeness) from the Isha Upanishad.
शून्यं न संकेतः। परमेश्वर सत्ता।
The Nirvana Upanishad states, "Shunya is not just the gesture; the ultimate is Shunya" emphasizing the ultimate reality as emptiness.
ॐ पूर्णमदः पूर्णमिदं पूर्णात्पूर्णमुदच्यते।...
On the other hand, the Isha Upanishad states, "Om. That is whole; this is whole From wholeness, wholeness comes out" highlighting the idea of wholeness.
How do these seemingly contrasting concepts of Shunya and Purna coexist and complement each other within the Upanishadic tradition?
Any thought on this?

It is better not to compare early upanishadic ideas (13 principal upanishads) with later sectarian upanishads. Isha is one of the early upanishads. Nirvana is one of the 108 minor upanishads, to be specific, sannyasa upanishads. the nirvana upanishad idea is very close to Buddhist view, not really classical hindu view. all hindu philosophies (vedantic subschools) are based on only principal upanishads.

there is a philosophical school in buddhism known as shunyavadis or madhyandin school.

@AmritenduMukhopadhyay side question. what are 13 principal Upanishads? Can you please list them for me?

To see the list search for the words "principal upanisads" here.  https://saraswat-prakashan.weebly.com/hindusastras-english.html

@Rasik Isha, Kena, Katha, Prasna, Mundaka, Mandukya, Aaitareya, Taittiriya, Chhandogya and Brihadaranyaka. Some adds Kaushitaki and Maitrayini in this list.
